# getJSON issue with loading images across Safari and iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image, preloading

I'm trying to load a series of images that disappear at an interval of 300ms on page load.

The images are chosen at random from a JSON file, based on the users screen dimensions.

This works in Chrome but seems to fail randomly, and does not work at all in Safari (pauses on a random image) or on iOS (fails to load any images at all).

Here is my code:

```
// get the screen orientation based on css media query
var orientation = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/['"]+/g, '');

window.slides = [];

// function to randomise the order of an array
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( 'html' ).addClass( 'js' ).removeClass( 'no-js' );

  // define the category and number of slides
  var imageDirs = { "lovers": 16 };

  // get slide urls from json file
  $.getJSON('slides/slides.json', function (data) {
    for (var thisDir in imageDirs) {
      var theseSlides = [];
      theseSlides = data[thisDir][orientation];
      shuffle(theseSlides)
      slides = theseSlides.slice(0, imageDirs[thisDir]);
    }
  })
  .done(function() {
    // randomise order of slides
    shuffle(slides);

    // have one blank slide at the beginning of the animation
    slides.push("initial-slide.png");

    if ( slides.length ) {
      for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        $('#wrapper').append('<img class="slide" src="slides/' + slides[i] + '">');
      }
    }
  });
});

$(window).on('load', function(){
  // wait for images to load before displaying animation
  $('#wrapper').waitForImages(true).done(function() {
    $('#preloader').remove();

    var currentSlides = [];

    $('.slide').each(function(){
      currentSlides.push($(this));
    });

    // remove slides at an interval of 300ms
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      if (currentSlides.length){
        currentSlides.pop().remove();
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertirish/6g41vwnL/59/

Live site: http://robertirish.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a fiddle or something, but at least one of your issues stems from using setInterval. I take it you want this to occur every 300ms? One slide, then the next, then the next, yeah? As you have it, this will only occur once. You need to setup a recursive setTimeout. This is a great article that explains scheduling and the differences between setInterval and setTimeout: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. It does loop through all the images—in Chrome! Just not on Safari or on iOS, where it doesn't display anything at all...

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertirish/6g41vwnL/59/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the fiddle. Basically your problem is that in your `load` event the images haven't been appended to be the DOM yet. You can see this by logging `currentSlides`: https://jsfiddle.net/1fb3gczq/

So, you need to ensure the DOM is ready before you manipulate it. I've moved your function to the ajax success which works in this case, but on slower connections you'll want to only run the effect once all the images have loaded in the DOM. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcx3w48b/

Comment: Thanks for this James, that's a huge help. Have you got an idae about how would I go about telling when all the images have loaded in the DOM? I'm a little fuzzy on order of operations as I'm new to getJSON and ajax.

Comment: I think I've sorted out that issue using the waitForImages jquery plugin.